# Android SMS more than 160 characters

Tags: android, sms

Hi I am trying to send sms to different mobile numbers with different text body, my code is also sending sms more than 160 characters but it sends to only one number not to all , Now I want to send multiparttext message to all contact list.pls help

private void sendSMS()

```
{
        if (list_phone.size()!=0){

            //new AddNewCategory().execute();
            for (i = 0; i < len; i++){


        SmsManager sm = SmsManager.getDefault();  
        ArrayList<String> message_parts = sm.divideMessage(list_MESSAGE_BODY.get(i));

       // Log.e("Message parts 3", message_parts.get(3));
       // Log.e("Message parts 4", message_parts.get(4));
        Intent iSent = new Intent();
        PendingIntent piSent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this, 0, iSent, 0);
        Intent iDel = new Intent();
        PendingIntent piDel = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this, 0, iDel, 0);

        if (message_parts.size() == 1)
        {
            String msg = message_parts.get(0);
            sm.sendTextMessage(list_phone.get(i), null, msg, piSent, piDel);
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), " Message sent", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

        }
        else
        {
            ArrayList<PendingIntent> sentPis = new ArrayList<PendingIntent>();      
            ArrayList<PendingIntent> delPis = new ArrayList<PendingIntent>();       

            int ct = message_parts.size();
            for (int i = 0; i < ct; i++)
            {
                sentPis.add(i, piSent);
                delPis.add(i, piDel);
            }
            //Log.e("Message Parts", message_parts+"");
            Log.e("Phone list", list_phone.get(i));
            Log.e("Message parts"+i, message_parts.get(i));
            sm.sendMultipartTextMessage(list_phone.get(i), null, message_parts, sentPis, delPis);
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), " Message sent", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();    

        }   
        }
        else
        {
            // Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Phone list is empty.. Message not sent", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();    
        }



}
```

Answer (score 0):

you need added ";" after each number.

I give one example , Please check it and give your problem solution.

```
protected void sendMsg(Context context, SmsMessage smsMessage) {
        SmsManager smsMgr = SmsManager.getDefault();
        ArrayList<string> smsMessageText = smsMgr.divideMessage(smsMessage.getMsgBody());
        PendingIntent sentPI = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, 0, new Intent("SMS_SENT"), 0);
        PendingIntent deliveredPI = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, 0, new Intent("SMS_DELIVERED"), 0);
        int AddresseesPerMessage = 10;
        StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
        String delim = "";

        for (ContactItem c:smsMessage.getAddresseeList()) {
            //  For every phone number in our list
            builder.append(delim).append(c.getPhoneNumber().toString());
            delim=";"; /// if have SAMSUNG devices then  delim=", ";
            if (((smsMessage.getAddresseeList().indexOf(c)+1) % AddresseesPerMessage) == 0 || smsMessage.getAddresseeList().indexOf(c)+1 == smsMessage.getAddresseeList().size()) {
                // using +1 because index 0 mod 9 == 0 
                for(String text : smsMessageText){
                    //  Send 160 bytes of the total message until all parts are sent
                    smsMgr.sendTextMessage(builder.toString(), null, text, sentPI, deliveredPI);
                }
                builder.setLength(0);
                delim="";
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this code

```
{
if (list_phone.size()!=0){

//new AddNewCategory().execute();
            for (i_m = 0; i_m < len; _mi++){
SmsManager sm = SmsManager.getDefault();  
        ArrayList&lt;String&gt; message_parts = sm.divideMessage(list_MESSAGE_BODY.get(i_m));
// Log.e("Message parts 3", message_parts.get(3));
       // Log.e("Message parts 4", message_parts.get(4));
        Intent iSent = new Intent();
        PendingIntent piSent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this, 0, iSent, 0);
        Intent iDel = new Intent();
        PendingIntent piDel = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this, 0, iDel, 0);
if (message_parts.size() == 1)
{
            String msg = message_parts.get(0);
            sm.sendTextMessage(list_phone.get(i), null, msg, piSent, piDel);
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), " Message sent", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}
        else
{
            ArrayList&lt;PendingIntent&gt; sentPis = new ArrayList&lt;PendingIntent&gt;();      
            ArrayList&lt;PendingIntent&gt; delPis = new ArrayList&lt;PendingIntent&gt;();       
int ct = message_parts.size();
            for (int i_t = 0; i_t < ct; i_t++)
{
                sentPis.add(i_t, piSent);
                delPis.add(i_t, piDel);
            }
            //Log.e("Message Parts", message_parts+"");
            Log.e("Phone list", list_phone.get(i));
            Log.e("Message parts"+i, message_parts.get(i_m));
            sm.sendMultipartTextMessage(list_phone.get(i), null, message_parts, sentPis, delPis);
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), " Message sent", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}   
        }
        else
{
            // Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Phone list is empty.. Message not sent", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();    
        }
}
```